How to parametrize trefoil knot with arbitrarily shaped cross section
I've been trying to add one or two dimensions to the following threadlike trefoil knot
$$\mathbf r(t):
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&x=\sin(t)+2\sin(2t)\\
&y=\cos(t)-2\cos(2t)\\
&z=-\sin(3t)
\end{aligned}\right.\!,\ t\in[0,2\pi]$$
The method I had thought up was adding a vector to $\mathbf r$ which will describe the section and that lies on the plane perpendicular to the tangent vector, $\hat{\dot{\mathbf r}}$. Namely, a vector described by the normal and binormal vectors (obtainable via Frenet-Serret formula's). So basically the resultant parametric surface would be
$$\mathbf{\tilde r}(t,\theta)=\mathbf r(t)+\rho(\theta)\cos\theta\,\mathbf N+\rho(\theta)\sin\theta\,\mathbf B$$
To upgrade to the third dimension we could parametrize some geometric constant inside $\rho(\theta)$ which is proportional to the distance. For instance, if the section were to be a circle, then $\rho=R$ for $R\in[0,\text{radius of section}]$.
I've applied the method for the surface using Python but didn't get what I predicted (the section isn't what's supposed to be). What other methods do you propose?

This looks reasonable. Give specific examples of what you tried and what went wrong. I suspect your $\mathbf N(t)$ and $\mathbf B(t)$ are incorrect.

Pardon, I just noticed I wrote the wrong formula for $\mathbf T$ in my code, it looks as though it works fine now, thanks.
